# UnsupportedMediaException:supported ones are [application/soap+xml] error is thrown

Tags: java, xml, web-services, maven, soap

can you guys tell me why am getting this exception. This works well in project A as such but I actually merged the project A into Project B and started noticing this error while calling the payment authorization soap service.

am i missing any maven dependency? Please help me

```
com.sun.xml.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: text/xml Supported ones are: [application/soap+xml]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:322)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAP12Codec.decode(StreamSOAP12Codec.java:107)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:156)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:312)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:272)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:221)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:110)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1063)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:979)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:950)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:825)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:443)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:174)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:154)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.authorize(Unknown Source)
    at com.macys.mkp.Utils.MkpCreateOrderServiceUtil.EPSService(MkpCreateOrderServiceUtil.java:103)
    at com.macys.lib.utils.AuthorizeSteps.sendAuthorizeRequest(AuthorizeSteps.java:102)
    at com.macys.lib.utils.AuthorizeSteps.createAuthorize(AuthorizeSteps.java:82)
    (reflection-invoke)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator$ParametrisedStep.perform(StepCreator.java:599)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$FineSoFar.run(PerformableTree.java:340)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you put the right content-type in the header?